# mysql calculate between beyond two dates

Tags: mysql

I have sql query that calculate assigned hours when the Start and End meet.

here is my sqlfiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f7634/1

```
SELECT `Nickname`, `taxemployee_id`, `taxemployee`.`id`, `taxemployee`.`Position`, COALESCE((datediff (`end`, `start`) + 1), 0) * `assigned_hours` as assigned_hours, start,end
FROM (`taxemployee`) 
LEFT JOIN `project_staff_assignment` ON `project_staff_assignment`.`taxemployee_id` = `taxemployee`.`id` 
    AND start >= '2014-09-01' AND end <= '2014-09-15'
    AND end <= '2014-09-15' AND start >= '2014-09-01'    
GROUP BY `taxemployee`.`id` 
ORDER BY `Nickname` ASC
```

The query show all records between 2014-09-01 to 2014-09-15.

what if I have a record that the Start value is 2014-09-01 End is 2014-09-30 I cant get any result between this dates.

here is my insert record.

```
(7, 5, 'Senior2', 12, '7', '2014-09-01', '2014-09-30', 'active')
```

I need to return value given the query above. maybe my query is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think you want overlaps with the period, if I understand correclty.  If so, try this:

```
SELECT `Nickname`, sa.taxemployee_id, e.`id`, e.`Position`,
       sum(datediff(least(end, date('2014-09-15')), greatest(start, date('2014-09-01'))) * assigned_hours) as assigned_hours,
       start, end
FROM taxemployee e JOIN 
     project_staff_assignment sa
     ON sa.`taxemployee_id` = e.`id` AND start <= '2014-09-15' AND end >= '2014-09-01'   
GROUP BY e.`id` 
ORDER BY `Nickname` ASC;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f7634/18) is the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: @Strawberry . . . Because I think the OP wants to add up all hours during the date range.  The original query has a `group by`.

Comment: @Strawberry . . . I wish you were clearer.  I was missing the `sum` on the hours.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with this...

```
SELECT t.Nickname
     , psa.taxemployee_id
     , t.id
     , t.Position
     , psa.start
     , psa.end
  FROM taxemployee t 
  LEFT 
  JOIN project_staff_assignment psa
    ON psa.taxemployee_id = t.id;

+----------+----------------+----+-----------------+------------+------------+
| Nickname | taxemployee_id | id | Position        | start      | end        |
+----------+----------------+----+-----------------+------------+------------+
| Walter   |           NULL |  1 | Partner         | NULL       | NULL       |
| Eric     |           NULL |  2 | Partner         | NULL       | NULL       |
| Richard  |           NULL |  3 | Partner         | NULL       | NULL       |
| Elaine   |              4 |  4 | Senior Manager  | 2014-08-18 | 2014-08-22 |
| Tan-tan  |           NULL |  5 | Senior Manager  | NULL       | NULL       |
| Alvin    |              6 |  6 | Senior Manager  | 2014-08-01 | 2014-08-15 |
| Alvin    |              6 |  6 | Senior Manager  | 2014-08-18 | 2014-08-22 |
|          |           NULL |  7 | Senior Manager  | NULL       | NULL       |
| Jackie   |           NULL |  8 | Manager 2       | NULL       | NULL       |
| Ayee     |              9 |  9 | Manager 2       | 2014-08-01 | 2014-08-01 |
| Dan      |             10 | 10 | Manager 2       | 2014-08-11 | 2014-08-15 |
| Acel     |           NULL | 11 | Manager 1       | NULL       | NULL       |
| Nim      |             12 | 12 | Manager 1       | 2014-09-01 | 2014-09-30 |
| Joem     |           NULL | 13 | Asst. Manager 2 | NULL       | NULL       |
| Jen      |           NULL | 14 | Asst. Manager 2 | NULL       | NULL       |
| Joanne   |             15 | 15 | Asst. Manager 2 | 2014-08-25 | 2014-08-29 |
| Berenice |           NULL | 16 | Asst. Manager 1 | NULL       | NULL       |
+----------+----------------+----+-----------------+------------+------------+
```

Now, given this intermediate result, what would the desired result look like?